# How to align fields in discord.py embedded messages

Tags: python, formatting, discord, discord.py

I am creating an embedded discord.py message that will look like [image]

Each field's value has a string consisting of words and a new line followed by each word. As you can see though, the formatting is slightly off and the columns aren't exactly centered. How can I achieve this?

My discord embed code:

```
embed = displayembed('Live Match Data')
embed.add_field(name = 'Blue Team', value= a1, inline = True)
embed.add_field(name = 'Champion', value = a2, inline = True)
embed.add_field(name = 'Rank', value = a3, inline = True)

embed.add_field(name = 'Red Team ', value = b1, inline = True)
embed.add_field(name = 'Champion', value = b2, inline = True)
embed.add_field(name = 'Rank', value = b3, inline = True)

embed.set_footer(text = ctx.author.name, icon_url = ctx.author.avatar_url)

await ctx.send(embed = embed)
```

Comment: You can't because embeds are very limited in terms of formatting and are rendered differently on every device/resolution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
embed = discord.Embed(title='Live Match Data')
embed.add_field(name = 'Blue Team', value= "Something", inline = True)
embed.add_field(name = 'Champion', value = "Something", inline = True)
embed.add_field(name = 'Rank', value = "Something", inline = True)

embed.add_field(name = 'Red Team ', value = "Something", inline = True)
embed.add_field(name = 'Champion', value = "Something", inline = True)
embed.add_field(name = 'Rank', value = "Something", inline = True)

embed.set_footer(text=ctx.author.name, icon_url = ctx.author.avatar_url)


await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you explain what the difference is between the code OP posted?